# Angular ng-messages, any opportunity for DRY?

Tags: angularjs, validation

**My Code**

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="yourFirstName">Your First Name</label>
        <input id="yourFirstName"
               name="yourFirstName"
               class="form-control"
               required=""
               ng-model="myModel.yourFirstName"
               type="text" />
        <div ng-messages="myForm.yourFirstName.$error" ng-if="myForm.$submitted || myForm.yourFirstName.$touched" class="errors">
            <div ng-messages-include="template/validation/messages.html"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The amount of times I repeat the field name `yourFirstName` seems ridiculous

Is there any way to reduce this?

**Update:**

`template/validation/messages.html`

```
<span ng-message="required">Required Field</span>
<span ng-message="min">Too small</span>
<span ng-message="number">Must be a number</span>
<span ng-message="odd">Odd numbers only</span>
```

Comment: What does `template/validation/messages.html` look like?

Comment: Added it, it's not 100% done yet.. still in development

Comment: The only thing I would say is that if you change your styles and wrap the `input` in the label you can get rid of the redundant `for` and `id`.  `ng-model` is required to use the data in your form and `name` is required so you can reference it for validation purposes.